# Lograr busqueda filtrando informacion en mongodb y tambien crear una consulta agrupando por un campo, moongose y nodejs

Tags: mongoose

Mi colección se llama "items" y ésta es la estructura de mis documentos, aquí un ejemplo:

```js
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6461847a25d52e5c960a0ed0"),
    title: 'Monopatin ZU07-350w',
    department: 'items',
    category: 'Movilidad Personal Electrica',
    sub_category: 'Monopatines Electricos',
    state_use: 'nuevo',
    tecnicalDescription: 'Nuevo en su caja',
    generalMessage: 'Traidos de China ',
    images: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    price: 360,
    published: true,
    state_province: 'Bolívar',
    stock: true,
    favorite: 0,
    user_id: '6435c5a0f33a6fca623f340b',
    username: 'gregoriom',
    createdAt: 2023-05-15T01:01:46.339Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-05-15T01:01:46.339Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Ahora muestro la ruta donde hace la búsqueda :

```js
routes.get('/view-items', async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.session.user
  const searcher = req.query.search;
  req.session.search = searcher;
  const Searcher = req.session.search;
  delete req.session.search;

  if (searcher) {
    console.log("este es el user desde la view-artes: ",  user);
    console.log("Aqui debomostrar un resultado de consulta --->", searcher);
    const cardArticleItems = await modelItems.find(
      { title: {$regex: searcher , $options: "i" }
    });
    console.log(cardArticleItems);
    res.render('page/view-items', { user, cardArticleItems, Searcher })                                                                        
  } else {
    console.log("este es el user desde la view-artes: ",  user);
    const cardArticleItems = await modelItems.find()
    res.render('page/view-items', { user, cardArticleItems, Searcher })
  }
});
```

Como se puede observar `cardArticleItems` tiene la búsqueda por el campo `title` que logra filtrar de un campo que tengo en el *front* que es enviado al *backend* por *query* llamado "searcher".

Todo aquí funciona de maravilla pero yo no solo necesito que me haga el filtro de los productos que cumplen con la búsqueda, también requiero poder crear un nuevo objeto que pueda tener los `states_province`  en grupo .

Ejemplo de lo que desearía:

```js
db.items.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$state_province", "repetido" : {$sum : 1} } }
]);

// SALIDA:
[
  { "_id" : "Carabobo", "repetido" : 1 }
  { "_id" : "Táchira", "repetido" : 2 }
  { "_id" : "Distrito Federal", "repetido" : 1 }
  { "_id" : "Bolívar", "repetido" : 5 }  
]
```

Resumen de lo que quiero lograr:

1. Mi búsqueda tal cual la tengo esta perfecta. Desearía quedara así.
2. Lograr otro objeto que pueda enviar al *front* para mostrar grupos de estados con su cantidad y se verias así:

> Carabobo (1)
>
> Tachira (2)
>
> Distrito Federal (1)
>
> Bolívar (5)

Yo sé construir la vista. Lo que quiero es ayuda con el código Mongoose para lograr el segundo objeto que me produzca ese agrupamiento.

No se cómo hacerlo en Mongoose, agradecería mucho su ayuda. Por favor. No se cómo hacer una búsqueda, filtrar y luego lograr ese agrupamiento.